# Dose HyperLedger Composer v0.20.4 support Fabric v1.4?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am using HyperLedger Composer and Fabric to develop my blockchain system.The current version of in my system is: Composer v0.20.4 and Fabric v1.4.
I want to upgrade fabric to v1.4. Does the composer support this version?If it does not apply to the version(1.4), how can I use the new feature of fabric?

Comment: Fabric v1.4 hasn't been released yet, but once it is available we will run our builds against this version to check that it tolerates this release. It has already been done against 1.4.0-rc1 and the builds passed so we are hoping that it will continue to work. You should ensure you always use the latest level of 0.20.

Comment: Composer may "tolerate" Fabric 1.4, but it is very unlikely that it will take advantage of any new Fabric features.  If you want to use new Fabric features you will need to develop your smart contract (chaincode) using native fabric, and applications using one of the Fabric SDKs.

Answer (score 2):

Composer 0.20.6 has been released with toleration support for Hyperledger Fabic 1.4. By toleration support that means it will work but not exploit any new features in fabric. In fact Composer 0.20.x does not exploit any new capabilities delivered in Hyperledger Fabric 1.2, 1.3 or 1.4.

Composer will not support the next major release of Hyperledger fabric which will be a Version 2 release.